# reshape2: recasting molten dataset gives wrong result

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, reshape2

I get a feeling I am missing something basic, yet cannot figure it out.

Trying to melt a dataset and recast into original form, but it doesn't work.

```
library(reshape2)

df <- structure(list(measure1 = c(4.11000246380076, 4.29087381534614, 
4.30709021582289), measure2 = c(1.71250102658365, 1.78786408972756, 
1.79462092325954), measure3 = c(86.3932114427626, 84.6768654385354, 
86.9635134280892)), .Names = c("measure1", "measure2", "measure3"
), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Original dataset:

```
  measure1 measure2 measure3
1 4.110002 1.712501 86.39321
2 4.290874 1.787864 84.67687
3 4.307090 1.794621 86.96351
```

Molten dataset:

```
df <- melt(df)

  variable     value
1 measure1  4.110002
2 measure1  4.290874
3 measure1  4.307090
4 measure2  1.712501
5 measure2  1.787864
6 measure2  1.794621
7 measure3 86.393211
8 measure3 84.676865
9 measure3 86.963513
```

Trying to recast into original shape, but the output is weird:

```
df <- dcast(df, value ~ variable)

      value measure1 measure2 measure3
1  1.712501       NA 1.712501       NA
2  1.787864       NA 1.787864       NA
3  1.794621       NA 1.794621       NA
4  4.110002 4.110002       NA       NA
5  4.290874 4.290874       NA       NA
6  4.307090 4.307090       NA       NA
7 84.676865       NA       NA 84.67687
8 86.393211       NA       NA 86.39321
9 86.963513       NA       NA 86.96351
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to add an identifier variable to `df`: `df2 <- df; df2$id <- row.names(df2); mdf2 <- melt(df2); dcast(mdf2, id ~ variable)`